# Sybase buffer cache error while retrieving data from table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

Hi I am very new to Sybase IQ, I'm inserting data into 309 columns at once. While I was retrieving I am getting the below error.

[image: Buffer Cache error]

***Tagged Sybase ASE only in a view that you might have knowledge on IQ as well**

Comment: buffer cache is likely a server configuration value that is set by the dba.  That's  how many of those settings work in ASE.  Maybe `commbuffersize`?

Comment: How did you try to insert the data?

Comment: I am using load table command to insert data @frlan

Answer (score 0):

The default IQ buffer cache sizes of 16MB for the main cache and 8MB for the temporary cache are too low for any active database use. You need to set the buffer cache sizes for the IQ main and temporary stores in one of two ways:

- To set buffer cache sizes server-wide for the current server session, specify the server startup options -iqmc (main cache size) and -iqtc (temp cache size). Recommended method.
- To set cache sizes for a database, you can use the SET OPTION command to set the Main_Cache_Memory_MB and Temp_Cache_Memory_MB database options. This method only lets you set values less than 4GB.

You can find more details here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1260/html/iqapg/iqapg58.htm

Comment: There is no change in main or temp buffer cache @dom

Comment: @Chakri i don't get it. the error message above is very clear: the system does not have enough buffer cache. so have you tried increasing the buffer cache?